# @ sign at the end of symbol name in object file

Tags: linker, cygwin, mingw, symbols

Say in my system in jpeg library:

```
$ > nm libjpeg.a | grep jpeg_finish_decompress
00000510 T _jpeg_finish_decompress
```

But in openjpeg library:

```
$ > nm lib/libopenjpeg.a | grep opj_decode_with_info
00000240 T _opj_decode_with_info@12
```

The latter has @12 at the end. I guess 12 is the total size of the arguments.
Nevertheless why some symbols have @-ending?
The question arises when I tried to compile mupdf library. It links ok against jpeg
library for example but fails to link agains openjpeg.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **name mangling**. It is used even for plain c code, not only c++.

Next example is from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). Next function definitions:

```
int _cdecl    f (int x) { return 0; }
int _stdcall  g (int y) { return 0; }
int _fastcall h (int z) { return 0; }
```

give these symbols:

```
_f
_g@4
@h@4
```